# How do you add a custom column to a query in sqlalchemy if you are using the classical mapping?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Some caveats:

1. Our models are generated from yaml file, and we don't have a way to add a computed property via the yaml file at this time (we will eventually)
2. Given the above, we don't have models to add hybrid properties to.

What is the proper way to add a computed column to a query, such that it is included in the returned object, and not as a separate entry in a returned tuple?

```
db_query = session.query(Listing)
db_query = db_query.add_column("1 as listing_test")

print(self.db_query)
## this looks good.
# SELECT listing.id AS listing_id, 1 as listing_test
# FROM listing 
# WHERE listing.id = :id_1

self.db_query.all()
## this looks bad.
# [(<flask_sqlalchemy.Lease object at 0x7fca868ff1d0>, 1)]

self.db_query.column_descriptions
[{'aliased': False,
  'entity': <class 'flask_sqlalchemy.Lease'>,
  'expr': <class 'flask_sqlalchemy.Lease'>,
  'name': 'Lease',
  'type': <class 'flask_sqlalchemy.Lease'>},
 {'aliased': False,
  'entity': None,
  'expr': '1 as listing_test',
  'name': '1 as listing_test',
  'type': NullType()}]
```

Ideally, instead of the tuple that is being currently returned, the listing_test is just a part of of the returned listing object.

Comment: I haven't tested or done this, but you might be able to achieve this using [reflection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html#overriding-reflected-columns).

Comment: I think you can add columns and properties to the class after it's generated, i.e. `Listing.listing_test = Column(...)`. I'm not certain whether you need to do it before the mapper is configured on the class.

Answer (score 0):

@univerio got me very close!

I had to set it as a column property, and then all was well.

```
class Listing(db.model):
    custom_function = column_property(func.custom_function(id))
```